# Character class regex confusion

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to abbreviate a regex in a grep. I need to match exactly six spaces followed by an alpha character. This works:

```
grep "^\s\s\s\s\s\s[[:alpha:]]" <filename>
```

This does not:

```
grep "^[[:space:]]{6}[[:alpha:]]" <filename>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the topic, `[:space:]` matches tabs, newlines, vertical tabs, form feeds, carriage returns, and spaces, and  `[:blank:]` matches spaces and tabs.

Comment: @Christopher With GNU `grep`, `\s` is a synonym for `[[:space:]]`, so the conversion is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{6}` is an extended regular expression "bound" that won't work in basic regular expressions (it would match `{6}` literally).  The `grep` utility is using basic regular expressions by default.

Two solutions:

1. Use `\{6\}` instead, which is how you'd write it in a basic regular expression.
2. Use `grep -E`, which enables the use of extended regular expressions in `grep`.

Also, if you want to match spaces (and no other characters; `[[:space:]]`, as well as `\s` in GNU `grep`, matches space, vertical/horizontal tab, form feed, newline, and carriage return), use a literal space. For example,

```
grep -E '^ {6}[[:alpha:]]'
```

Related:

- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to what Kusalananda said, you could also use `egrep` if you don't feel like dealing with the `-E` flag.

Comment: Do note that POSIX is/has been moving towards a single `grep`, away from grep/fgrep/egrep. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html

Comment: Oh really? I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The [GNU grep man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html) is explicit, saying `egrep` etc are deprecated.